# Selected Image URL is not being set when using multiple CKEditor instances

Tags: image, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor 3.5.6 in an existing client site.  They have a form page that has a short and long description for a product.  Both fields are text areas that are converted to ckEditor instances on page load.  In general they work fine, however, when we use the select image option and pick an image, the URL is not being set in the image URL field on the Image Properties popup.

If I only init one of the two instances, the URL is selected and set correctly.

I read from some searches that this is probably a case where ckEditor can't determine which field to populate, so it does nothing. However upon inspection, it looks like I getting unique function references passed to the browse image window:  CKEditorFuncNum=1  and then CKEditorFuncNum=93.

So here's my setup. Would love some help to determine why this isn't working.

**HTML / JS:**

```
<textarea id="Short_Desc" name="Short_Desc"></textarea>
<textarea id="Long_Desc" name="Long_Desc"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var shortEditor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'Short_Desc', {toolbar : 'Basic', height:150, toolbarStartupExpanded: false});  

    var longEditor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'Long_Desc', {toolbar : 'Default'});  
</script>
```

**GLOBAL CKEDITOR CONFIG:**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.emailProtection = 'encode';
    config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = true;
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    config.templates_replaceContent = false;
    config.skin = 'silver-master';
    config.format_tags = 'p;pre;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;div;address';
    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
    config.IgnoreEmptyParagraphValue = true;
    config.height = 400;
    config.allowedContent = true; 
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe[*]|[id](*)';
    config.extraPlugins = 'iframe';
    config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g);

    config.toolbar = 'Default';

    config.toolbar_Default = [  
        ['Source','Maximize'],['Templates'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','SpellChecker','Scayt'],
        ['Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Superscript'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
        ['TextColor','BGColor'],['Link','Unlink'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Image','MediaEmbed','Table','HorizontalRule','fileicon','SpecialChar'],
        ['Format','Font','FontSize']
    ];

    config.toolbar_Basic = [
        ['Source','Maximize'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['TextColor','BGColor'],
        ['Link','Unlink'],
        ['Image','Flash','MediaEmbed','fileicon','SpecialChar'],
        ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize']
    ];

    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.admin&select=image&fieldname=fckeditor' ;
    config.filebrowserWindowHeight = 680;
    config.filebrowserWindowWidth = 880;
};
```

These are the URLs that are sent to my image selection window from the IMage Properties' "Browse Server" button:

short desc:
http://www.example.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.admin&select=image&fieldname=fckeditor&CKEditor=Short_Desc&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

long desc:
http://www.example.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.admin&select=image&fieldname=fckeditor&CKEditor=Long_Desc&CKEditorFuncNum=93&langCode=en

Comment: The question is: what's the response that you send from the server?, specially to the long desc request.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are registered globally (via `CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction`) so CKEditor should always know which editor instance they belong to. You can test image URL insertion manually (the first argument is your CKEditorFuncNum (1 or 93):

```
CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, '/path/to/your/image');
```

If you can insert images correctly this way, the problem is likely to be with your custom image browser. Otherwise I would consider upgrading CKEditor. I was able to use multiple instances with image browser without any problems in v. 4.*.